# mysql query skips first row

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sqlList ="select title from podcast order by date_pd desc limit 5";
$rslt2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlList) or die ("Fail".mysqli_error($conn));         
$record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2);          
$nRows = mysqli_num_rows($rslt2);
for ($i=0; $i<$nRows; $i++) {
        $record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2);  
        echo $record2["title"];
}
```

the echo result is skipping the first row of the query, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by `first row` here?

Comment: You could try using `while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2))` instead of counting rows and using a for loop. Could save some trouble

Comment: maybe that's sixth by date?

Comment: sorry, the first element, in this case the first title

Comment: `while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2)){echo $record2["title"].'<br/>';}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the line `$record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2);`, which is placed before the for loop.

new code would be:

```
$sqlList ="select title from podcast order by date_pd desc limit 5";
$rslt2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlList) or die("Fail".mysqli_error($conn));                 
$nRows = mysqli_num_rows($rslt2);
for ($i=0; $i<$nRows; $i++) {
    $record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2);  
    echo $record2["title"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are loosing the first row of your result set because you read the first row and throw it ways/ignore it

```
$sqlList ="select title from podcast order by date_pd desc limit 5";
$rslt2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlList) or die ("Fail".mysqli_error($conn));         

// this line gets the first row of your result set 
// and you just ignore it therefore throw it away
$record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2);          

$nRows = mysqli_num_rows($rslt2);

for ($i=0; $i<$nRows; $i++) {
        $record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2);  
        echo $record2["title"];
}
```

As @Anant says, you are better advised to use a `while` as if the result set is empty, it just does nothing. Admittedly not always an advantage.

```
$sqlList ="select title from podcast order by date_pd desc limit 5";
$rslt2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlList) or die ("Fail".mysqli_error($conn));         

while ( $record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt2) ) {
        echo $record2["title"];
}
```